# Is there a way to automate filling in the Store listing tab of Chrome extension to the Web store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I went through the API but couldn't find a way to fill in the chrome webstore submission form programmatically.
Since filling in manually all the description for each of the locales is very time consuming and painful, so my focus is on automating that part specifically.
[image]

Inside there we have to fill forms for each locales like this:
[image]

I am not looking for automatic translation. I have the translated texts already. I just want to automate the filling of forms.